# prevent keyboard from moving specific layout up

Tags: android, layout, android-constraintlayout

I have TextInputEditText which have another layout below it. When the TextInputEditText is focused I hide the layout below it and show the keyboard. When the user is done with the writing I hide the keyboard and immediately set the invisible layout back to visible. The problem is the layout starts above the keyboard and when the keyboard is down it gets back down. this takes few miilseconds but makes a bad effect.

To clarify, I want to prevent keyboard from moving specific layout up.

```
   input.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus) {
                view.findViewById(R.id.colorbtnlayout).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                view.findViewById(R.id.outlinelayout).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                view.findViewById(R.id.bottombuttons).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                view.findViewById(R.id.bottombuttons).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  For this question, I would suggest either re-writing it or include screenshots/video and be as clear as possible... it's a bit hard to understand what youre' asking.

Comment: Sorry, all I want it prevent keyboard from moving specific layout up.

Answer (score 2):

just add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in your activity in `manifest.xml`

Comment: But I want the TextInputEditText to move up. adding android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" will prevent everything from moving